# Как поместить график в ячейку dataframe pandas и потом скачать этот dataframe в excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

Есть код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.random(10)*10
y = np.random.random(10)*20

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["agg", "v", "pic"])

data.loc[len(k1)] = ['1', 'k', sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y)]
data
```

Выводит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачиваю таблицу:

```
k1.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

Файл скачивается без рисунка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу, чтобы мой график находился в столбце "pic", и потом таблицу сохранить в excel файле.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону pandas + xlsxwrite http://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/